# Unwanted rotation behavior

Tags: animation-nodes

The Cube should rolle like a cube should roll^^. In some cases the rotation goes wrong in case of a gimbal lock? How to avoid that?
[image: GIF]

[image: PNG]

Comment: I don't know Animation nodes, but can it do [axis-angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) or [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). Those don't gimbal lock.

Comment: Yes, it has axis-angle and quaternions. But I don't know how to set this up. It's pretty new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rotation behavior occurs because the first rotation causes a rotation in the axes as well. This would require you to recalculate the axis to use for the second rotation. Unfortunately this problem isn't the result of gimbal lock and won't go away if you're switching to quaternions.

A quick and dirty solution would be to change the order of your rotations depending on whether the cube is rolling in the x or y direction. I don't know if it's possible to change the rotation order for one node, but if you multiply the rotation matrices you end up with the same result. If you're sticking to nodes, use two *Matrix Math* and a *Matrix Mix* node. I just decided to switch to a script to reduce the amount of wiring.

[image: Rolling Cube]

This approach would require you to keep track of the cube's direction and manually add keyframes for the script input which changes the matrix multiplication order.

The fact that the orientation of the cube might change whenever you switch could lead to problems if you replace the cube with an object with less symmetry. But then it might be better to search for another approach as the x and y position of an empty alone isn't sufficient to determine the desired orientation of the final object.

[image: order of rotation is important]

Comment: Thank You for helping me. I can't test the script because of an TypeError in [Line:3 - can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' (TypeError)]

Comment: @DanielGlebinski The input types for the script should be *Float* for both *x* and *y* and *Boolean* for the third value. I assume you picked *Float List* and tried to pipe *Location* directly into the script.

Comment: Sorry, was my fault. I used the Script Node incorrectly.

Comment: Still dirty but beautiful^^ Maybe I could automate the boolean with a case function. In one case the whole geometry flips and if the cube were detailed or textured asymmetrical it would flip and the flip would be recognizable. Works fine, thank you @binweg.